# getting warning in uitextfield's delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uitextfield

I'm new in iphone development.now, I'm facing one warning in my project.while,setting the delegate of UITextfield in ios 6 I'm getting the warning that

```
 "**incompatible pointer types sending 'class' to parameter of type '<uitextfielddelegate>'**"


+(UITextField*)tableLabelForText:(NSString *)txt frame:(CGRect)frm isEditable:(BOOL)isEditable 

{

    UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frm];
    [txtField setEnabled:isEditable];

    [txtField setText:txt];

    [txtField setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [txtField setDelegate:self];

    return txtField;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign the delegate in a class method which has no idea of the initialised object. Hence the warning. What you need to do is setDelegate to the initialised object.

```
[txtField setDelegate:<MyObject>];
```

Or you can as one of the answers suggests change the class methods to instance method.

```
-(UITextField*)tableLabelForText:(NSString *)txt frame:(CGRect)frm isEditable:(BOOL)isEditable
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Class level method "**+**" to return a text field instance, change it to Instance Level Method "**-**". i.e:

```
-(UITextField*)tableLabelForText:(NSString *)txt frame:(CGRect)frm isEditable:(BOOL)isEditable
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong , you are setting Delegate for an NSObject class ,
as NSObject class does not have any views , so UITextFieldDelegate does not confirms to the class. Instead use UIView

```
@interface ClassName : UIView  <UITextFieldDelegate>
```